# Boundary conditions for image transformations with meshgrid

Tags: image-processing, numpy

I transformed an image using `meshgrid`, but the new coordinates are partially outside the range of the original image, causing the transformation to fail.

First I used clip

```
...
tX = numpy.clip(tX.astype(numpy.int),0,image.w)
tY = numpy.clip(tY.astype(numpy.int),0,image.h)
result image([tX,tY])
```

which resulted in effect similar to the 'nearest' boundary condition.

I would like for all the outside pixels to be black. I thought I could achieve this by using a boolean array on the meshgrid, but I don't know how to apply the boolean array to the meshgrid correctly.

```
tXbool = numpy.abs(tX) < image.w
tXbool.shape
(850, 1280)
tX[tXbool].shape
(193180,)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, thats how I did it in the end:

```
tXbool = (0 < tX) & (tX  < image.w )
tybool = (0 < tY) & (tY  < image.h )
outliers = tXbool & tybool

mask = where(outliers,1,0)
mask4channels = dstack([mask,mask,mask])
image = image*mask4channels
```

Answer (score 1):

You should always apply the inverse transformation to the pixels in the *target* image and use this to look up the (interpolated) colour/value in the source image. Otherwise you'll end up with holes and quantization problems. Here's a reference, or look up image transformations/warps in any image processing textbook: http://www.cs.clemson.edu/~dhouse/courses/405/notes/image-warps.pdf

Comment: That is a very good point you made. It is very important to pay attention to that.